# Unable to print all title of product using Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webdriver

Here is my i want to scrape but it create problem it not scrape all products name here is the webpage from where i want to scrape https://ella-rue.com/collections/clothing

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/chromedriver.exe')

url= "https://ella-rue.com/collections/clothing"
driver.get(url)
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1
time.sleep(4)
"""last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

this doesn't work due to floating web elements on youtube
"""

last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
conte = None

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height and conte:
       print("break")
       break
    last_height = new_height
    time.sleep(5)
    pageSource = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
    conte = soup.find_all('div',class_='products grid grid--uniform grid--view-items flex flex-wrap') 
for items in conte:
    try:
        title= items.find('div',class_ = 'h4 grid-view-item__title').text
    except:
        title=''
    print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all titles from all pages, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://ella-rue.com/collections/clothing"

page = 1
while True:
    print("Page {}...".format(page))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(url, params={"page": page}).content, "html.parser"
    )

    titles = soup.select(".grid-view-item__title")
    if not titles:
        break

    for t in titles:
        print(t.text)

    page += 1
```

Prints:

```
Page 1...
JORJA SWEATER 
MOXIE DRESS 
JANSEN TOP 
SAFFRON DRESS 
KIMBERLY BIKINI SET 
BONITA DRESS 
HARBOR BIKINI SET 
VYOMA PULLOVER 
RUFFLE MINI SKIRT 
SANTINELLA PANT 
TRISTAN PANT 
ASHLAND PULLOVER SWEATER 
KIRBY HOODIE 
FANTASIA SUIT 
DEMETER SUIT 
CADEN DRESS 
SKINNY RACER MIDI TANK DRESS 
3 STRAP SKINNY RACER 
ALISSAR TANK 
CROPPED CAP TOP 
ARCHER DRESS 
DENVER DRESS 
AUGUSTINE DRESS 
Esme Dragonfly Roselle Linen Dress 
Page 2...
ARLO DRESS 
AYA DRESS 
EMILIA SKIRT 
CALVIN CASHMERE CARDIGAN 
CALVIN CASHMERE PANT 
VERENA SWIM SUIT 
KIMBRA DRESS 
LARSEN CARDIGAN 
ALBEE PULLOVER 
ANGIE DRESS 
MONROE SKIRT 
COSMO DRESS 
JULES TOP 
MERCY DRESS 
POSY SUIT 
GINGER BIKINI SET 
Page 3...
```

Comment: i want to get price and img kindly help me